# Can't add handshake parameter when authenticating socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I'm using socket.io V1.2.1 & trying to follow the [official Socket.io authorization wiki page](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing), but it seems it is a little bit outdated (may be written for version 0.9), so after making a few changes, here is my code for starting my server & configuring the authentication:

```
server = http.createServer(app)
io = require('socket.io')(server)
global.io = io
global.liveTopicIo = io.of "/live-topic"
server.listen(3100)
io.set 'authorization', (handshakeData, callback)->
    # doing some authentication logic here 
    # & reading 'currentUser'
    if isAuthenticated
        handshakeData.user = currentUser
        callback null, true
    else
        callback null, false

liveTopicIo.on "connection", (socket) ->
  console.log 'user: ', socket.handshake.user
  console.log 'a user connected'
```

the previous code prints the following

> user:  undefined
>
> a user connected

So, why I can't add parameters to the `handshake` data? & how to fix this to add current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [the migration notes from 0.9 to 1.x](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/), authorization shouldn't depend on the `set` function anymore, but instead should be a normal express middleware, so it should be like this:

```
liveTopicIo.use (socket, next)->
    # doing some authentication logic here based on the info 
    # from socket.handshake & reading 'currentUser'
    if isAuthenticated
        socket.handshake.user = currentUser
        next()
    else
        next(new Error("Access Denied"))
```